# Making an SVG wider or longer based on click and drag

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, svg

I have an upcoming project where I will need to customize the shape of an SVG when the user clicks and drags the extremity of said SVG. So for example a rectangle's corner is clicked and dragged and the corner maybe moves with it and when the user unclicks/mouseups the shape is then transformed. It's new shape extends to where the user let go of their mouse.

Does anyone have any pointers or references to how I would accomplish this? So resizing the path and shape based on where the user drags to?

I have an elaborate idea where I would maybe use the Framer Motion library and implement restrictions and if the user grabs a point and drags the SVG there will be an invisible radio input that is visible on hover and then have a custom Javascript function on the input that detects if the user is hovered over and the mouse is down and then when the mouse is up and it selects the radio button, which then triggers a state change and that change resets the path and there is an animation that changes the shape of the object.

I also saw Raphael.js could be an option but I'm not sure it accommodates SVGs.

Wondering if anyone has had any experience with this sort of thing and if there is an easier approach. I'll be using REACT.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could increase the "size" inside the SVG but I doubt that's what you want. Note that you can just put CSS "width" and "height" on an SVG and animate it like that.

I suggest this plugin although I haven't used it myself:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-resizable

Comment: Demo available here: https://strml.github.io/react-resizable/examples/1.html

Comment: Thanks! I don't think it's exactly what I need but it could come in handy! Appreciate it.